# Backbone: Singleton views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, singleton, backbone-views

I got several different views which are mostly built up like (layout-component, layout, main view).

When I now switch between different views the whole page has to get rerendered.

Wouldn't it be better to cache at least the layout view in "window" and reload them?

Something like a singleton pattern for backbone views?

How do I do this?
Is a simple:

```
window.MainLayoutView || window.MainLayoutView = new MainLayoutView({ el: 'div.main' });
```

enough?

Is there anything else I have to think about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is more to worry about. If you do something like this:

```
window.MainLayoutView.render();
$(x).html(window.MainLayout.el);
// And later...
$(x).html(someOtherView.el);
// And later still...
$(x).html(window.MainLayout.el);
```

you'll find that all your events inside `window.MainLayout` are gone. If you want to cache the instantiated view and swap it in and out, you're going to have to arrange [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) calls to rebind all the events all the way down the view hierarchy.

Compare the behavior of these two examples and you'll see the problem:

- http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Mrt3C/ (no `delegateEvents` calls).
- http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Mrt3C/1/ (with `delegateEvents` calls).

Generally you don't bother trying to cache views, just [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) them and recreate them as needed.

Comment: using .append doesn't cause the event reference to be lost.. .html actually gets the html as a string, so you're not even really referencing the view el..

Comment: @Stephen: But you're not going to use `append` to replace content unless you `empty` first, the effect will be the same (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dcFDL/). And I think you're confused about how `.html()` works (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3ZJCq/).